# Trouble with For Each or filtered array SwiftUI with Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore, foreach, swiftui

I have a project I'm working on that I started back in early 2020.  It was working fine when I stopped on it.  I recently started it back up and now three views no longer work.  The only common ground I can find is that they are the only swift files that have ForEach in them.  The code for the three vies is attached below.

I have tried commenting out blocks of code and the issue seems to revolve around the filteredDeals and the ForEach loop using that same variable.  It comes from a view model, which that code is also attached below.

I'm new to the stack overflow forum so if there is other relevant information I can provide please let me know.  Thank you in advance!

First View

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Foundation
struct DealList: View {
    
    //Set the background color to clear
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    //Activate the viewmodel
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = DealsViewModel()
    
    //Activate User settings
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GlobalSettings
    
    //View design
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Food Deals")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .padding()
                                    .padding(.leading,10)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Text("Selected day is " + "\(settings.SelectedDay)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .padding(.horizontal,8)
                                
                                //Navigation links that allows the user to filter by day of the week
                                NavigationLink(destination: FoodFilterForm(),
                                               label: {
                                        Text("Filter")
                                            .bold()
                                            .padding(.all, 10)
                                            .background(Color.gray)
                                            .cornerRadius(5)
                                            .shadow(radius:5)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                               })
                            }
                            
                      let filterDeals: [Array] = "\(settings.SelectedDay)" == "Everyday" ? viewModel.deals : viewModel.deals.filter { $0.dayofweek == "\(settings.SelectedDay)" }
                        
                            
                            // Loop through each deal and display them in a list
                            ForEach(filterDeals) { deals in
                                NavigationLink (
                                    destination: DealDetails (deals: deals),
                                    label: {
                                        
                                        HStack(spacing: 6.0) {
                                                //Image(systemName: "circle")
                                                    // .resizable()
                                                    //.frame(width:25, height:25)
                                            
                                            Text("\(deals.dealInfo)" + " @ " + "\(deals.restaurant)" + " on " + "\(deals.dayofweek)")
                                                .fontWeight(.light)
                                                .frame(minWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: 400, minHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealHeight: 50, maxHeight: 150, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                                .padding(.vertical, 7)
                                                .padding(.horizontal,10)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                        }
                                        .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)))
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                                        .padding(.horizontal,8)
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            // Hide the navigation bar in the navigation view
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            .onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                  }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Second View

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Foundation

struct DrinkList: View {
    
    //Set the background color to clear
    init(){
            UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    //Assign a value to deals to be called later
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = DrinksViewModel()
    
    //Activate User settings
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GlobalSettings
    
    //View design
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Drink Deals")
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .padding()
                                    .padding(.leading,10)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Text("Selected day is " + "\(settings.drinkSelectedDay)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white) 
                                
                                //Navigation links that allows the user to filter by day of the week
                                NavigationLink(destination: DrinkFilterForm(),
                                               label: {
                                        Text("Filter")
                                            //.font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                            .padding(.all, 10)
                                            .background(Color.gray)
                                            .cornerRadius(5)
                                            .shadow(radius:5)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                               })
                            }
                           /* // Loop through each deal and display them in a list
                                ForEach(viewModel.drinks) { drinks in
                                    NavigationLink (
                                        destination: DrinkDetails (drinks: drinks),
                                        label: {
                                            
                                            HStack(spacing: 8.0) {
                                                    //Image(systemName: "circle")
                                                        // .resizable()
                                                        //.frame(width:25, height:25)
                                                
                                                Text("\(drinks.dealInfo)" + " @ " + "\(drinks.restaurant)" + " on " + "\(drinks.dayofweek)")
                                                    .fontWeight(.light)
                                                    .frame(minWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: 400, minHeight: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, idealHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                                    .padding(.vertical, 7)
                                                    .padding(.horizontal,10)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            }
                                            .padding(.vertical, 2)
                                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)))
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                                            .padding(.horizontal,8)
                                    })
                                } */
                        }
                    }
            }
        
            // Hide the navigation bar in the navigation view
        }.navigationBarHidden(true)
         .onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Data Model

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class DealsViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var deals = [Deal]()
  
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
  func fetchData() {
    db.collection("storeDeals").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
      guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
        print("No documents")
        return
      }

      self.deals = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Deal in
        let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        
        let dealInfo = data["dealInfo"] as? String ?? ""
        let restaurant = data["restaurant"] as? String ?? ""
        let dayofweek = data["dayofweek"] as? String ?? ""
        let imageDestination = data["imageDestination"] as? String ?? ""
        let dealImage = data["dealIamge"] as? String ?? ""
        let cityAddress = data["cityAddress"] as? String ?? ""
        let address = data["address"] as? String ?? ""
        let phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"] as? String ?? ""
        let latitude = data["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0
        let longitude = data["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0
        let isFeatured = data["isFeatured"] as? Bool ?? false
        let isManagerAccepted = data["isManagerAccepted"] as? Bool ?? false
        let startTime = data["startTime"] as? String ?? ""
        let endTime = data["endTime"] as? String ?? ""

        return Deal(dealInfo: dealInfo, restaurant: restaurant, dayofweek: dayofweek, imageDestination: imageDestination, dealImage: dealImage, cityAddress: cityAddress, address: address, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, isFeatured: isFeatured, isManagerAccepted: isManagerAccepted, startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? All you've said is that "now three views no longer work". How so? They don't display any data? There's a compilation error? Ideally, you'd pare this down to a [mre] -- is the Firebase part integral to the problem? It sounds like it may not be if your suspicion is that the issue revolves around `ForEach`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, there is a compilation error that returns the following message: "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions." I have tried removing specific bits of code and that's what left me with the ForEach appearing to be the main culprit.  I will try to minimize it down as far as I can get and return back with what I can find.

Comment: Unfortunately, without a [mre], this won't be possible to debug definitively for you. Have you taken the advice of the error and tried breaking parts of the code out into smaller subviews?

Comment: I'm posting my findings, it's not really related to the initial title but in case it's helpful.  Something was wrong with the line: Text("\(deals.dealInfo)" + " @ " + "\(deals.restaurant)" + " on " + "\(deals.dayofweek)"). As soon as I changed that to just Text("\(deals.dealInfo)") it worked just fine.  Not sure what is causing that but wanted to provide an update.  Thanks to everyone who helped out!

Comment: Instead of using +, why not just include everything in the same string?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).